# How am I a born Muslim?

Tags: quran, interfaith

Technically, I'm a born Hindu, but:

How can you prove that I had a WILL right after I was born and that I submitted myself to the almighty Allah, hence making me a Muslim?

Or, does it all boils down to faith?

Comment: What kind of 'proof' are you looking for? Technically its impossible to prove 'will' if someone can't communicate language.

Comment: My guess is that the proof is the same as the one that made you say "I'm a born Hindu", or does it all boil down to heritage?

Comment: I knew it's gonna backfire at me. So, when I said I'm a born Hindu, I meant I was born into a family who happens to believe in Hinduism. Anyways, my conclusion is that it all DOES boils down to faith...

Answer (score 2):

As per Islamic belief, each child is born on fitrah (born with an innate inclination of tawhid or monotheism). Then his parents teach them their religion.

i.e *if a human being was raised out of societal norms, it is human nature that he/she will have a sense of God and will have an internal moral compass of what is right and wrong.*

> حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدَانُ، أَخْبَرَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ، أَخْبَرَنَا يُونُسُ،
>   عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي أَبُو سَلَمَةَ بْنُ عَبْدِ
>   الرَّحْمَنِ، أَنَّ أَبَا هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَالَ قَالَ
>   رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ مَا مِنْ مَوْلُودٍ إِلاَّ
>   يُولَدُ عَلَى الْفِطْرَةِ، فَأَبَوَاهُ يُهَوِّدَانِهِ أَوْ
>   يُنَصِّرَانِهِ أَوْ يُمَجِّسَانِهِ، كَمَا تُنْتَجُ الْبَهِيمَةُ
>   بَهِيمَةً جَمْعَاءَ، هَلْ تُحِسُّونَ فِيهَا مِنْ جَدْعَاءَ ‏"‏ ثُمَّ
>   يَقُولُ ‏{‏فِطْرَةَ اللَّهِ الَّتِي فَطَرَ النَّاسَ عَلَيْهَا لاَ
>   تَبْدِيلَ لِخَلْقِ اللَّهِ ذَلِكَ الدِّينُ الْقَيِّمُ‏}‏
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "No child is born except on Al-Fitra
>   (Islam) and then his parents make him Jewish, Christian or Magian, as
>   an animal produces a perfect young animal: do you see any part of its
>   body amputated?" Then he rec 'The religion of pure Islamic Faith
>   (Hanifa),(i.e. to worship none but Allah), The pure Allah's Islamic
>   nature with which He (Allah) has created mankind. Let There be no
>   change in Allah's religion (i.e. to join none in Allah's worship).
>   That is the straight religion; but most of men know not..." (30.30)
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari »  Vol. 6, Book 60, Hadith 298](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/44530)

I'd also like to clarify based on your question that Muslims believe that Islam is not a new religion that began in the 7th century. They believe it is the final form of the religion being propagated from Adam (AS) through Noah, Abraham, Moses, Jesus, Muhammad (PBUT) including a total of 124000 prophets spread across human existence on this planet.

The basic message of all Prophets was the same. **There is only a single God** and He alone is worthy of worship.

I invite you to join a course on comparative religion in your country. It opens up several avenues to see the similarities and differences between major world faiths and how religion has evolved over time.